# Change the time of day for rolling in logback

Tags: logback

How do I configure [`logback`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicy) to change the time of day for it's automatic rolling? I can't find it in the manual... Here's my logback.xml snippet:

```
<appender name="data" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>mylog.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: I tried writing my own `timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy`, but too much of it is private and I would have to write the whole thing from scratch. I think the the hardcoded rollovers are done in `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.RollingCalendar`, and there's no way to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known unsupported feature.

[[JIRA] (LOGBACK-205): rotate at an absolute time every day](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-205)

Perhaps if I get time I will submit a pull request.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do like this, Hope it will work for you.

```
<appender name="FILE"
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<File>${LOGDIR}/filename.log</File>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- rollover daily -->
    <FileNamePattern>${LOGDIR}/file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
    </FileNamePattern>
    <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
    <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
    <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 10MB -->
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <Pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
    </Pattern>
</encoder>
```

The above code will compress your file on the day basis or If the log file size exceeds 10MB.

Note : I have added "%i" in filePattern, It will iterate your file name as file1,file2 etc.

Comment: I don't want to roll based on file size, I want to roll based on time of day.